# Select more than one row inside sub query or evade sub query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to know how to realize query which selects sum of time column grouped by clientid column WHERE clause is divided by months and department from the same table:

table is the following:

[image]

The goal here is to have final result like the following:

**result 1.0**

```
------------------------------
clientid | december| february
------------------------------
1        | 2:20    | 4:00
------------------------------
2        | 4:00    | 7:00
------------------------------
```

Result will be displayed in the following manner:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Clientes</th>
      <th>January</th>
      <th>February</th>                                                         
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($stmt as $row)
{   
echo"
<tr>
  <td>".$row['clientid']."</td>
  <td>".$row['january']."</td>
  <td>".$row['february']."</td>                               
</tr>"; }; ?>              
</tbody>
</table>
```

In the following case scenario of query:

```
SELECT t.clientid, t.department, 
                        (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) ) ) FROM time_management WHERE YEAR(date)='$year' AND MONTH(date)= 12 AND department = '$department' GROUP by clientid  ) as january,
                        (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) ) ) FROM time_management WHERE YEAR(date)='$year' AND MONTH(date)= 2 AND department = '$department' GROUP by clientid ) as february
                        FROM time_management t WHERE t.department = '$department' GROUP by t.clientid
```

I get error: **SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row**

Since the sub query's are returning more than one row.

Without GROUP BY inside the sub query's the result is the following:

```
1   06:20:00    11:00:00                                            
2   06:20:00    11:00:00
```

So my question is how to structure the query in order to get the desired result showed in **result 1.0**

Any help will be very welcome. Thank you!

Comment: How do you want to handle when you have multiple years? all Dec get setup as Jan and all feb as feb even spanning years?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: What you're trying to do is called "pivot table". Unfortunately MySQL doesn't seem to have built-in support for that (unlike some other DBs), the linked question has some info about how to work around PIVOT being missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use subqueries. You can use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(`date`) = 2 THEN TIME_TO_SEC( `time` )  ELSE 0 END) AS February,
       SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(`date`) = 12 THEN TIME_TO_SEC( `time` )  ELSE 0 END) AS December
FROM time_management
WHERE t.department = '$department'
GROUP BY clientid
```

This way you can calculate the `SUM` of `time` for each month of the year.

Comment: do you have a typo in the first query? 2 instead of 12? or is this deliberate?

Comment: The idea is to select the 2 months at the same time. February and December. will that case select only one of the 2 months ?

Comment: @davejal `2` is for `February`, whereas `12` is for `December`. I have included these months because of the sample data provided in the OP

Comment: @JohnSiniger Each `CASE` calculates the `SUM` for one month. You can include `12` separate `CASES` in order to calculate the `SUM` for every month.

Comment: This seems to be working very good, any hint by the way how to visualize the sum of the time as time ? how it shows as seconds

Comment: @JohnSiniger use `SEC_TO_TIME`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(`date`) = 2 THEN TIME_TO_SEC( `time` )  ELSE 0 END) AS February,
       SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(`date`) = 12 THEN TIME_TO_SEC( `time` )  ELSE 0 END) AS December
FROM time_management
WHERE t.department = '$department'
GROUP BY clientid
```